# No audio in my HP Elitebook (Conexant ISST Audio)

Tags: windows-10, audio, hp-elitebook

I am having problems with my HP Elitebook audio for quite sometime now. Every now and then (more often these days), I stop getting audio from my laptop speaker. When I troubleshoot, it reinstalls the drivers (Conexant ISST Audio) and on restarting the machine the speaker works fine. However within some time (sometimes the same day) I again lose audio and I have to follow the same process again. At times I get audio rendering error in youtube and the same process needs to be followed.

Can anyone help me with the solution. I am running Windows 10.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have the latest audio drivers installed?

Comment: The windows reinstalls the driver every time that the audio runs in to a problem. I am assuming it is picking up the latest driver. Or is it not?